# Mapping a dictionary with multiple values to key using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

location column sample:

```
file= pd.DataFrame(columns = ['location'])
file['location'] = ['India, city3','city3','city2','china']
```

new_dict sample (it is a defaultdict):

```
new_dict = {'India':['India','city1', 'city2', 'city3'],'China':['China','city4','city5']}
```

Expected Output:

```
India
India
India
China
```

Sample Code:

```
for x in file['location']:
    for Country,Cities in new_dict.items():
        if re.findall('(?<![a-zA-Z])'+str(Cities).lower()+'(?![a-zA-Z])', str(x).lower()) != None:
            file['COUNTRY'] = Country
```

I am currently trying to map the Cities to Country using a dictionary. I am trying to incorporate some regular expressions in together because the column `location` will not provide an exact match. I am receiving this error `bad character range i-d at position 1408`. Please let me know how i can solve this.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions

1) how to map Cities to Country using a dictionary

2) receiving error > bad character range i-d at position 1408

Comment: I can map cities to countries but it is only taking exact matches. And not picking up anything else eg. city1,India would not be picked up. Only exact match eg. city2 or India

Answer (score 1):

First you need flatten your newdict by using  `ChainMap`

```
from collections import ChainMap
d = dict(ChainMap(*map(dict.fromkeys,new_dict.values() , new_dict.keys())))
d
Out[49]: 
{'China': 'China',
 'India': 'India',
 'city1': 'India',
 'city2': 'India',
 'city3': 'India',
 'city4': 'China',
 'city5': 'China'}
```

Then we using `replace` and `split` to yield the result

```
sample_df.replace(d,regex=True).location.str.split(',').str[0]
Out[53]: 
0    India
1    India
2    India
3    china
Name: location, dtype: object
```

Comment: hi sorry i didnt make myself clear. the code above works. however, it does not work for all the rows because not all of it are in the same format. eg. 'shanghai,china' , 'china,shanghai', 'shanghai, china, building three' etc.